# copy every 7th row from column A1 to column B1 in excel

Tags: excel, copy

i have A1 column with roughly 1000 record i want to copy just only every 7th record(cell A1,A7,A13..etc) to column B1(in the same sheet) any formula can help me in this issue
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MOD function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MOD-function-9b6cd169-b6ee-406a-a97b-edf2a9dc24f3)

```
=IF(MOD(ROW() - 1, 6) = 0, A1, "")
```

Place it in B1 and drag it down.

Results from rows: 1, 7, 13, 19, 25, 31, ...

Comment: pnuts, thank you for help in post editing. I'm sorry, but I'm not fluent in English. And, the second, I'm VB-programmer and my hands could not tag formulas as "code" ;) Now I know that they (formulas) needs in tag "code" too. Thank you once more.

Comment: Isn't this more or less a copy of the function I have in my answer? You match against mod() = 0 by -1 instead of me doing =1?

Comment: Andreas, hello. TS wrote: _"any **formula** can help"_.  Your header: _"You can use **VBA**"_. Was I obliged to read further more?.. How could I guess that somewhere in the middle of the text & pics you will return to TS needs?..   
In the rest - yes, there is no difference in principle. I'm sorry that it happened, but it was in your power - how to present information ... Prompt please, how you see  - by which way I should fix it? Priority is yours, it's not discussed...

Comment: So it's my job to make sure you read the answers? Ok. Sorry. I failed. The reason for , as opposed to ; is an excel setting.

Comment: My comment was not at you pnuts. But in my opinion when people do not tag vba, that is because they have no clue it exsists

Answer (score 1):

You can use VBA to do it. That way you don't have formulas on cells that you don't want to copy.

```
Sub test()


LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To LastRow Step 6
    Range("B" & i).Value = Range("A" & i).Value
Next i

End Sub
```

It will copy row 1, 7, 13, 19 etc. to column B.

You need to open VBA editor by pressing ALT+F11 and [Insert] [module].
Then just copy paste the code and run it.

If you do want to use a formula you can use this formula in column B.
Paste the formula in B1 and fill down.

```
=IF(MOD(ROW(A1);6)=1;A1;"")
```

[image]

Comment: ok thank you but to umprove this solution why b2 ,b3 is blank can it be fill so the value of A7 in B2 and value of A13 in B3

Comment: @saif didn't think that was what you wanted. If you don't mind the order you can just sort column B after you run the VBA code. Don't have time to edit anything now, have to go.

Comment: @saif I rekomend pnuts answer as it does exactly as you want.

Answer (score 1):

Copy A1 into B1 and in B2, copied down to suit:

```
=OFFSET(A$1,6*MOD(ROW()-1,7),)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
=INDEX(A:A,ROWS($A$1:$A1)*6-5)
```

if you want them without spaces in between.